# Countdown and Non blocking Input

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Hey there!**
I am trying to create a countdown that will print always in the same place.
This code worked on Linux but doesn't on windows:

```
import time
p = ">"
for i in range (0,19):
    print ("\r" + str(i) + "\t" + p, end='')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Now it prints row for row..
That is the easy part of my question. 
What I am actually seeking is an input under the countdown that won't cause the countdown to stop when an input is entered.
I am very new to programming, so I asked my oncle to help. He is trying to figure it out in Perl while I am searching a solution in Python 3! - With no luck so far.

Comment: Even if your oncle is doing this in perl, please don't tag the question perl, it has nothing to do with your question.